# Result is ok at preview, but empty after rendering

Tags: openscad

I want to cut this hemisphere:

[image]

my code is:

```
difference() {
import("../kupol.stl");
translate([-150,-1,-1]) cube(500);
}
```

at preview result is ok:

[image]

but after rendering (F6 key) I received an empty object:

[image]

Rendering was finished without any errors:

```
Compiling design (CSG Tree generation)...
Rendering Polygon Mesh using CGAL...
Geometries in cache: 15
Geometry cache size in bytes: 3178728
CGAL Polyhedrons in cache: 12
CGAL cache size in bytes: 0
Total rendering time: 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
Rendering finished.
```

I'm using OpenSCAD version 2015.03-2 at Windows 7 64bit machine.
[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14480974/) is detailed information about my build and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6eZzxZXMc-BYm9idXdEQU4xMkU/view?usp=sharing) is stl with hemisphere which I need to cut.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The STL has probably some problems. Make sure it's manifold (which can be checked with most mesh editors, e.g. MeshLab, Blender, Netfabb).

Also have a look at the [FAQ](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/FAQ) which explains an additional issue that can cause OpenSCAD to have problems with the STL (Zero-Faces = Triangles that have no area).

Comment: You was absolutely right! I fixed stl with https://netfabb.azurewebsites.net/ and now OpenSCAD works fine with it :)